# Resuming/Restarting the Elastic search transforms from stopped state automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

When Elastic search is stopped ( this could be for many reasons), the transform job's status will be moved from "start" to "stopped" state and doesn't restart or resume automatically when elastic search is started again.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

there's currently not, no

I would encourage you to open a feature request on GitHub for this though!